# SQL Server 'Delete From' Statement Conflicts

Tags: sql-server

When I am trying to delete from Company, the Error is:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CompanyUser_Company"
```

When I am trying to delete from CompanyUser, the Error is:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Company_CompanyUser"
```

What's the way to accomplish without disabling the Foreign Key Constraints, as this is live website and lots of transactions happen?

Comment: Why does `Company` reference `CompanyUser` and vice-versa? A user belongs to a company but a company also to a user?

Comment: I just checked and they definitely belong to each other. But a company can have more than one user obviously.

Comment: I agree with Tim Schmelter, this doesn't look right.
Could you provide more information on the database model? Is the table `CompanyUser` a junction table or just the table for the users?

Comment: It's just a table for users. To log in to a job-site, companies have many users who works at HR department.

Comment: Presumably, the reference from `Company` to `CompanyUser` is something like "this is *the* superuser for this company". However, this reference was initially established (probably insert to Company, insert to CompanyUser, update Company) needs to be reversed - set the "superuser" (or whatever it is) to `NULL` via an `UPDATE`, *then* perform the `DELETE`s.